# JavaScript using async/await to make sure I retrieve value before implementation, but still get 'undefined' returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

### Code

```js
async function getStudents() {
  var reqObj = new RequestHandler("/students/all/");
  let { students } = await reqObj.sendRequest();
  console.log(students, students.length);
  return students;
}

export default function Students(props) {
  var students = getStudents();
  return (
    <main className="content-section">
      <h1>Students</h1>
      <span className="help-text">
        You have {`${students.length}`} students.
      </span>
    </main>
  );
}

...

export class RequestHandler {
  // Base class for handling requests
  constructor(url, method = "GET", contentType = "application/json") {
    this.url = url;
    this.method = method;
    this.contentType = contentType;
    this.request_conf = {
      method: this.method,
      url: this.url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": this.contentType,
        "X-CSRFToken": cookies.get("csrftoken"),
      },
      credentials: "same-origin",
    };
  }
  async sendRequest() {
    const response = await axios(this.request_conf);
    var data = isResponseOK(response);
    return data;
  }
}
```

The `console.log(students, students.length);` within the `getStudents()` function gives me the output just as I expect: `[] 0`, but despite trying to make it an asynchronous function and all, the `Students` component still get `undefined` as value back.
What would be the easiest way to get the same value read within the `Students` component?

**DISCLAIMER**

I am a beginner at JavaScript and especially Promises, so if there's something really simple and/or obvious that I am missing here, please tell me so and don't be toxic about it :)

Comment: You forget awaiting your students in the caller too, but it is not your only problem, as Drew points out. That render method is supposed to be able to be called hundred times per second, so it can't block

Comment: @oligofren - Could you point to where exactly you mean? I am too big of a n00b to get it right away... :<

Comment: Both the answer by Ariart (now hidden) and drew has added the await construct for reference, and from the comments it seems that you understand it pretty well 

Comment: With regard to the blocking thing: react expects all render methods to execute almost immediately and return a result. Therefore any such method cannot spend time waiting for a network result. The actual call and any waiting needs to be processed "outside" of the method, hence the need for useEffect and useState

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "render" function of React is a synchronous, pure function. It can't wait for values to be rendered. This is what lifecycle methods and state are for.

Use `useState` hook to hold the `students` array in state, and an `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array to make the call to `getStudents` and await for the Promise to resolve and enqueue a state update and trigger a rerender.

```
export default function Students(props) {
  // state to hold values
  const [students, setStudents] = React.state([]);

  // effect to fetch values
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getStudents().then(students => setStudents(students));
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency == run once on component mount

  return (
    <main className="content-section">
      <h1>Students</h1>
      <span className="help-text">
        You have {`${students.length}`} students.
      </span>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Docs

- [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)
- [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

If you prefer `async/await` to Promise chains:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    try {
      const students = await getStudents();
      setStudents(students);
    } catch(error) {
      // handle error, log it, etc...
    }
  };
  fetchStudents();
}, []);
```

Comment: In the async/await version of the code that you wrote, wouldn't I have to write ```const students = await getStudents();``` ?

Comment: @W1ck3d Ah, yes, totally. Sorry, ‍♂️ that was a copy/paste error and I somehow dropped the `await` for the call. Thanks for noticing. 